# Is there a "Print Screen" command in Boot Camp on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook, boot-camp, screenshot

I have a MacBook Pro with Windows 7 installed on the Boot Camp partition. I've figured out how to invoke most of the "missing keys" (like home, end, page up, page down) but have not yet figured out if there are equivalents for "Print Screen" and "Alt+Print Screen". What are the keyboard shortcuts for this?

Answer (score 37):

In Boot Camp under Windows (XP or 7), the following works:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>: Print Screen
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>: Print Active Window

For more 'missing keys', see the following Apple Support page: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1220

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Snipping Tool` under accessories in the Start menu.
With that tool you can just select the area you want to copy and it will copy it to both clipboard and opens it in other window.

Comment: This is a great tool, but isn't useful for when you want to take screenshots of a menu structure, or anything else where losing focus will cause you to lose what you want to snip. This is where Print Screen is so useful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to Boot Camp in particular, but in general to using an Apple keyboard on Windows.

*If you plug in a PC keyboard it should work, and if you use an Apple keyboard on a Windows PC you should have the same problem.*

That said, there are programs that let you remap your keys, like [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) for OSX and [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665) for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

Fn + Shift + Option +  F11 (active windows)

https://support.apple.com/pt-br/HT202676

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> should do a Print Screen in Boot Camp.

Comment: Negative... that command reduces the volume of the speakers.

Comment: Hmm... for more suggestions see here - http://www.logicnest.com/archives/78 (especially the comments)

Answer (score -1):

Use the built-in program called "Snipping Tool".

Comment: The question is the keyboard short cut, not how to do a print screen.